# IE9 Rendering Blank when Page contains a Silverlightcontrol

Tags: silverlight, internet-explorer-9

We have an issue with IE9 rendering a blank page. This has been tested on multiple machines in live and development mode.

The page is a mix of items AJAX controls but the element causing the issue appears to be the Silverlight(4) control (disable that and everything works fine). Resize the browser window and the page is shown correctly.

This also happens on other pages on the site using Silverlight.

One suggestion was to use windowless=false.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this issue was to add an additional 'dummy' Silverlight control to the page. It then rendered correctly. I have no idea why this fixed the problem but it did.

Thanks for all suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I found a possible fix for this.  I realize this is an old post but I struggled with this problem forever.

If the silverlight control has 'windowless mode turned on

It will just show a blank page in IE9.  In windows 7, if you minimise the IE9 and then hover over the icon on the task bar, you can see the page as it should render in the little preview box.

It must be a problem with certain graphics accelerators\drivers and IE9.  If you go to the advanced options on Internet Explorer and check the box for 'Use Software Rendering instead of GPU rendering', there is a good chance that the page will display correctly.

So, either remove the windowless parameter from the silverlight app 
OR
Use Software Rendering instead of GPU rendering

Answer (score 0):

Always Always try installing latest all possible Windows updates.
This solved a very similar issue for me recently.
-- Lee